# How to add a view to another view in a certain condition?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, view

I'm working on an app and I want to add a view to the current view in a specific location if he checks a CheckBox but every time I try to add `parent.addView(child)` it crashes .. so I want to know how can I do this and how to release the view when the user clicks the CheckBox again.

That's a demo of what I want to make

https://xd.adobe.com/view/46d4808d-9888-455b-42ca-9fab587eb55d-30e5/

Answer (score 0):

you can set the visibility in the xml file to gone and then set it back to visible when you click on the check box

xml:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

jav:

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I really forget to mention that there will be 5 check boxes and adding the whole layout under every checkbox will make the code much much larger and may affect the performence so I hope there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Custom Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components) with the hidden content and reuse it in each checkbox. In addition, you can use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) to add the checkbox. Or you can even create the custom component with the checkbox and hidden content and put all the logic there.